# Loading Data by php Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: tabulator

I'm trying to load data from a database using a php file I have setup my html page as below but when I run it i'm getting console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at tabulatortest.html:38.

I found an example online on how to reference the php file and I have used that to create my html and php files.

can anybody let me know where I'm going wrong and why I'm getting the error?

Thanks I.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var table = new Tabulator("#tabulator-example", {
  layout: "fitColumns",
  responsiveLayout: "hide",
  tooltips: true,
  addRowPos: "top",
  history: true,
  pagination: "local",
  paginationSize: 10,
  movableColumns: true,
  resizableRows: true,
  initialSort: [{
    column: "subsystem",
    dir: "asc"
  }, ],
  columns: [{
      title: "Subsystem",
      field: "subsystem",
      minWidth: 20
    },
    {
      title: "Doc Number",
      field: "docNumber",
      minWidth: 20
    },
    {
      title: "Description",
      field: "docDescription",
      minWidth: 20
    },
    {
      title: "Discipline",
      field: "Discipline",
      minWidth: 20
    },
    {
      title: "Tag Number",
      field: "tagNumber",
      minWidth: 10
    },
  ],
});



// table.setData(tabledata);
$("#tabulator-example").tabulator("setData", "setData.php");
```

Comment: Have you included jquery?

Comment: I read that with Tabulator V4.1 there is no need

Comment: `$("#tabulator-example").tabulator("setData", "setData.php");` looks like a jquery `$` reference.

Comment: I added the jquery reference and the Tabulator jquery wrapper but still get the same error.

Comment: Can you post what you updated?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you seem to be using the old jQuery method in your code:

```
$("#tabulator-example").tabulator("setData", "setData.php");
```

You should instead be using the following to set the data in your table:

```
table.setData("setData.php");
```

If you want the data loaded into the table on load you can instead pass the url directly into the the ***ajaxURL*** option in the table definition, then you wont need to call ***setData*** at all:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#tabulator-example", {
  layout: "fitColumns",
  ajaxURL:"setData.php",
  ....
```

Have a look at the [Ajax Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/data#ajax) for full information on how to use this feature

Comment: Oli Many thanks, sorry I'm new to Tabulator and am more at home with PHP. I searched on a way to load data from mysql using php and json to tabulator and must have found an old method not suitable to v4.1. I really appreciate the quick reply directly from you.